# Quarkus testing libraries

Tags: java, testing, junit5, quarkus

We recently decided to create our new project using Quarkus. Now we struggling to make a decision which testing libraries we want to use:

- quarkus implementations ( for example `io.quarkus.quarkus-junit5`, `io.quarkus.quarkus-junit5-mockito`)
- standard testing libraries: `Junit5` + `Mockito`

We are already familiar with `Junit5` + `Mockito` non-quarkus implementations, so we don't need to learn anything new if we decide to proceed with those libraries

Using Quarkus libraries we have some new features available like `@InjectMock` or `@QuarkusTest`, which seems to keep Test classes more tidy.

What I am looking for is to find out if there are any reasons(except readability and less coding) to go with Quarkus libraries? If not I guess the preference for most java teams should be standard testing libraries usage.

Comment: `quarkus-junit5` or `quarkus-junit5-mockito` are not "Quarkus implementations" of JUnit 5 or Mockito. They give you the same JUnit 5 and Mockito libraries you're used to. On top of that, there's tight integration with Quarkus that allows easy testing of Quarkus applications. It is not either-or. You can use plain JUnit for unit testing components (unless those components are CDI beans, or some other reason why they need some sort of a container), and the Quarkus integration for integration testing the application.

Comment: I know that I can use plain JUnit for testing some components but the question is if I should do it? What's the difference here between `quarkus-junit5` and `junit5`?

Comment: Well It is supposed but not confirmed that using framework version should ensure classpath compatibility between your libraries, if you handle each library independently you will have to do this yourself, also the quarkus annotations do some sugar for you in terms of configurations and integration with other parts of the framework as it is testing with container builds with the QuarkusTestIntegration annotation and help you manage your test dependencies lifecycle out of the box with the QuarkusTestResourceLifecylce. @dgebert.

Comment: Thanks @karelss, I guess that's true, just not sure if that's enough to make educated decision to choose the correct approach

Comment: As said, when you are doing bare bone unit tests its best to use Junit5 + Mockito directly, while when you are doing component tests or whatever bigger tests you are doing with @QuarkusTest then you should use the Quarkus versions.

Answer (score 0):

As people mentioned in comments to your posts, quarkus implementation of junit5 and mockito is the same junit5 and mockito used in vanilla libraries, but with better integration with the quarkus framework. You should have move features making developer's life easier, especially when writing integration tests.

> What I am looking for is to find out if there are any reasons(except readability and less coding) to go with Quarkus libraries? If not, I guess the preference for most java teams should be standard testing libraries usage.

It depends on the team. If you plan to use your code only with quarkus, why not use the solution that makes writing tests easier? Do we have any high risk of using the quarkus testing framework? Also, if you encounter problems, switching back to the native junit-5 and mockito shouldn't be a high cost for the team.

Answer (score 0):

The quarkus-junit5 library is necessary for testing, as it includes the @QuarkusTest annotation to manage the testing framework. This annotation initiates the testing process in a Quarkus environment, where configurations are read, all beans are visible, and everything is initialized for testing.
For example for testing resources you will need full Quarkus environmnet initialized during tessting.

https://quarkus.io/guides/getting-started-testing

@InjectMock method can be used for any normal scoped CDI bean (e.g. @ApplicationScoped, @RequestScoped etc, basically every scope except @Singleton and @Dependent).

Instead of using "@InjectMock", you can still achieve the same functionality but with slightly more code by using "QuarkusMock.installMockForType()" or "QuarkusMock.installMockForInstance()".

```
@QuarkusTest
class Calculator2Test {

  Calculator calculatorMock;

  @BeforeEach
  void setUp() {
    calculatorMock = Mockito.mock(Calculator.class);
    Mockito.when(calculatorMock.sum(1, 1)).thenReturn(2);
    Mockito.when(calculatorMock.sum(2, 2)).thenReturn(4);
    QuarkusMock.installMockForType(calculatorMock, Calculator.class);
  }

  @Test
  void sum() {
    assertEquals(2, calculatorMock.sum(1, 1));
    assertEquals(4, calculatorMock.sum(2, 2));
  }
}
```

https://quarkus.io/guides/getting-started-testing#quarkus_mock

Instead, you can simply use "@InjectMock".

```
@QuarkusTest
class CalculatorTest {

  @InjectMock Calculator calculatorMock;

  @BeforeEach
  void setUp() {
    Mockito.when(calculatorMock.sum(1, 1)).thenReturn(2);
    Mockito.when(calculatorMock.sum(2, 2)).thenReturn(4);
  }

  @Test
  void sum() {
    assertEquals(2, calculatorMock.sum(1, 1));
    assertEquals(4, calculatorMock.sum(2, 2));
  }
}
```

https://quarkus.io/guides/getting-started-testing#further-simplification-with-injectmock

You can also check @InjectWireMock @InjectSpy.